# Need help to fix error and add FCM code in my Android app

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am adding Firebase Cloud Messaging.

When I go to add app level gradle code (line as mentioned below) as written on Firbase instructions:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I am getting error. Appreciate any help.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the `apply plugin...` statement to *after* the dependencies block:

```
dependencies {
    ...
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Update the version of all `play-services-*` and `firebase-*` libraries to at least 9.0.2.  The [current version](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases) is 10.2.1.  Be sure to use the same version of all  `play-services-*` and `firebase-*` libraries.